# fatal: could not parse HEAD after accidentally deleting the .git folder from my local project

Tags: git

I deleted my .git directory from my project folder with

because I experimented on some commands which is
$ rm -rf .git now I cannot commit it to a new repo, is there a way that I can push my project to a new repo, because I got this error already when I commit to a new repo

```sh
$ git status
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@panjeh/git-status-fatal-bad-object-head-af22724f48b9). But be warned! Before you start doing anything, manually copy the whole project folder to another location in your disk.

**Reason:**
More likely a disk error or an unclean PC or Laptop shutdown or disconnect suddenly and unsafely a hard drive from laptop could have left the repository in this state.

The consequence problem is that the ~/main_repo/.git directory of your repository is damaged.

There are several ways and methods to fix it but if you have a backup in GitHub or other online git repositories or another remote server, you can fix such errors easily.

**Solution:**
I assume you have a backup in github like:

```
https://github.com/your_account/backup_repo
```

So make a temp directory and then clone the backup repository in it.

Like:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/your_account/backup_repo.git
```

**Note**: Be careful for cloning the repository with suffix `.git` like above. If you put `backup_repo` instead of `backup_repo.git` then you can not find `.git` directory inside what you have cloned.

Then replace the broken `.git` folder with the one from the clone by `mv` or `cp -r` commands.

Comment: ok sir, thanks for dis.. Anyway, please hang on ok :) I'll need your help for more :D

Comment: Probably best to put the relevant parts of the post in your answer, because if that resource moves or is removed then your answer becomes useless. Also probably good to mention that that post requires a pre-existing backup of the entire repository.

Comment: @Gavin, it's not a backup friend.. It waslike my initial commit for like 20 days ago.

Comment: it's not a backup friend.. It was like my initial commit from like 20 days ago. & lots of changes have been made and I want to partner with my friend in developing because I can't focus on this project now that I have a job interview.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @TheBAST. Did the solution I've referred to work?

Comment: I'm saying that I have it in another repo cause I've changed the remote origin with ```remote set-url```..before issuing ```rm -rf .git```

Cause I have made a mistake with using git, it's been a long time, since I used it and I don't understand it at that time..

so what I did is I pushed my initial commit it to github so that people I know can collaborate on developing it. I made that commit for heroku setup, now I want to make a new commit to a new repo, but things got sour so I issued ```rm -rf .git``` I thought that was the right command to issue

Comment: so that was the repository that I've pushed to github my initial heroku setup for like 20 days ago

Comment: So what now friend?